# Get Value of Backspaced Character

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, backspace

I have a form with a keyboard on it. When a user types a letter it works like a GPS Feature and will only allow you to type the next letter according to the predictions database.

Likewise, when someone makes a mistake, that letter will be blacked out

So far I have the following code that works to capture the letter they deleted

```
dim lastLetter = Mid(RTextBox.Text, RTextBox.Text.Length, 1)
```

However when the person presses backspace on their keyboard, the letter is already removed and will not work with the above code

Is there a way to capture that letter before it gets removed from the textbox?

Comment: how about having a listener on the textbox that stores the value that's entered? (in say, ascii format)

Comment: they may backspace twice so wouldn't work the second time around

Comment: not if you store the full 'string' in ascii as it's typed?

Comment: it's in a different language, would that make a difference?

Comment: ascii is a standard encoding. So I don't believe so. (pretty much, design a simple keylogger). And, depending on the size of your input, you *should* be able to store the info in a local variable (try not to give it too much scope, or it may not be GC's after use)

Comment: or save the string, and when the 'backspace' character is pressed, get the last character using a substring/lastChar/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the keydown handler. In this example, c will have the character just backspaced over.

```
Private Sub rText1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
  Handles rText1.KeyDown

If e.KeyValue = Keys.Back Then c = rText1.Text.Chars(rText1.Text.Length - 1)
e.Handled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What does e.handled accomplish?

Comment: When true, it tells Windows that the key press has been taken care of or handled, and Windows doesn't need to process the key press further. In this case, the rich text box would never see the key press. When false, the rich text box will accept the keystroke as it normally would, after the handler exits.